# Rails Observers & Mailer

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, actionmailer, observers

I am trying to figure out how to send new users a welcome email.

I asked this question yesterday 
*https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31934734/rails-mailer-no-method-error?noredirect=1#comment51781688_31934734*
It voted down (I don't know how to find out why) and was not able to get any constructive help.

I've since found rails-observer gem and am trying another approach.

My problem is that when I push this and try it out, I get an error that says: NameError (uninitialized constant UserObserver::Mailer).

My understanding of that error is that that there isn't a model that matches the name of the observer. I definitely have a user.rb model and I also have a file in my app called Mailer.

I have the following set up:

In my model folder, I have user_observer.rb:

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(user)
      Mailer.welcome_mail(user).deliver!
  end
end
```

User/Registration_controller:

```
   def create
        @user = User.new(user_params) 

        respond_to do |format|
          if resource.save

            format.html { redirect_to(profiles_path)}
          else
            format.html { render action: 'new' }
            format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
          end
        end
      end
```

`app/mailers/welcome_mail.rb`:

```
class WelcomeMail < ActionMailer::Base
  self.delivery_method = :smtp
  self.smtp_settings = {
    user_name:            ENV['WELCOME'],
    password:             ENV['D_WELCOME'],
    port:                 ...,
    domain:               'gmail.com',
    address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
    authentication:       'plain',
    enable_starttls_auto: true
  }


def new_user_waiting_for_access(user)
  @user = user
  mail(to: user.email, from: "...@....com", subject: "Welcome #{user.first_name}")
end
end
```

`User.rb`:

```
  def send_user_welcome_mail
    AdminMailer.new_user_waiting_for_access(self).deliver
  end
```

`application.rb`:

```
config.active_record.observers = :user_observer
```

The specific error is:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant UserObserver::Mailer):
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002104+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user_observer.rb:3:in `after_save'
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002106+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:21:in `block in create'
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002108+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:20:in `create'
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002109+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002110+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002111+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002113+00:00 app[web.1]: NameError (uninitialized constant UserObserver::Mailer):
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002114+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/models/user_observer.rb:3:in `after_save'
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002116+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:21:in `block in create'
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002117+00:00 app[web.1]:   app/controllers/users/registrations_controller.rb:20:in `create'
2015-08-12T03:14:33.002118+00:00 app[web.1]:
```

I don't understand what this error means. I have a user observer which is supposed to observe user and send a mail when the user is saved.

The content of the email is set out in a view called: welcome_mail.html.erb.

Please can anyone see what I have done wrong?

I have commented devise confirmable out - so it is not looking for confirmation. I have read others problems who may be related to devise having a view folder called mailer. I don't know what that means in the context of this problem because I'm not trying to send the mail from devise.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your posted code you have this: `Mailer.welcome_mail(user).deliver!` which is wrong because you don't have a `Mailer` class defined and no `welcome_mail` method defined as well, so this approach is wrong.

I think you want to use your defined mailer class `WelcomeMail` and inside `WelcomeMail` class you have to define a `welcome_mail` method where you put the logic to send the mail to the user.

Somewhat like this:

```
class WelcomeMail < ActionMailer::Base     
  def welcome_mail(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://example.com/login'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to My Awesome Site')
  end
end
```

So, your `user_observer.rb` becomes:

```
class UserObserver < ActiveRecord::Observer
  def after_save(user)
      WelcomeMail.welcome_mail(user).deliver!
  end
end
```

Comment: Hi, I don't have a mailer called user_observer.rb. I have a model with that name (lower case). My mailer file is called app/mailers/welcome_mail.rb

Comment: @user2860931 Please look at my edit. I have pointed out the problems and showed you the possible solution. Give it a try and let me know if that works for you!

Comment: Hi there, I tried this suggestion, but I still get this error: NameError (uninitialized constant UserObserver::Mailer):

Comment: @user2860931 Did you restart your server after changing the codes?
Because you should not get the SAME error as you already changed your `Mailer.welcome_mail(user).deliver!` to `WelcomeMail.welcome_mail(user).deliver!`

Comment: I did restart the server. I also pushed to heroku and tried it live. In both cases, I get the same error.

Comment: You CAN'T get same error `NameError (uninitialized constant UserObserver::Mailer)` if you applied my code. It has to be something different :-) Because, in my code I don't have any `Mailer` class

Comment: When I try it with local host, I get: Missing template welcome_mail/welcome_mail with "mailer". When I try it with heroku, I get the error above

Comment: Try it locally first. Its good that you are having a different error now. Means, we are making progress :-)
So, you need to create a template for `welcome_mail` as the error message says.

Comment: I have a template. I have a view called views/welcome_mail/new_user_waiting_for_access.html.erb

Comment: @user2860931 works? awesome :-)
Consider upvoting my answer as well if you think it deserves one ;-)